# Why Does Code Keep Jumping to return main();?

Tags: c++, if-statement, char, adventure

Hey Guys I'm New To c++ and To practice I'm making a "Make Your own adventure game"
I Have No idea what the problem is I believe it has something to do with my char variable mainly I will be posting the code of my main.cpp How ever there are other external header files But I see no reason to post them also my code will run without giving me an error and I don't see how it can do that if my if else statement is broken/my char variable.

Thanks for the help.

```
#include <iostream>
//LVL1
#include "C:\Users\QuestionMark\Desktop\Make Your Own Adventure\LVL1\Dog.h"
#include "C:\Users\QuestionMark\Desktop\Make Your Own Adventure\LVL1\Dream.h"
#include "C:\Users\QuestionMark\Desktop\Make Your Own Adventure\LVL1\GTFO.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "Welcome to my 'MAKE YOUR OWN ADVENTURE GAME!!!'\n";
    cout << "Have Fun and enjoy the ride!\n";
    cout << "Would you like to put in a cheat code??\n";
    cout << "Yes or No, Cap Sensitive!\n";
        char y[3];
        cin >> y;
if(y == "Yes"){
        cout << "Please Enter Cheat Code now\n";
        char z[5];

    if(z == "Dog"){
        Dog();
    }else if(z == "Dream"){
        Dream();
    }else if(z == "GTFO"){
        GTFO();
    }else if(z == "Path"){
        Path();
    }else if(z == "Sword"){
        Sword();
    }else if(z == "Weird"){
        Weird();
   }else{
    cout << "Invalid Cheat Code\n";
    }
}else if(y == "No"){

    cout << endl;
    cout << "You wake up and your house is on fire what do you do ??\n";
    cout << "Quick Grab The Dog = 0, GTFO = 1, Go back to sleep = any other number\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    if(x == 0){
        Dog();
    }else if(x == 1){
         GTFO();
    }else{
         Dream();
   }

}else{
cout << "Invalid Answer\n\n\n";
return main();
}
return 0;
}
```

On a side note.
In The Header Dog I called All the functions for level2
And I'm just wondering why my program runs fine without me having me to call
all the level2 functions in my GTFO header and my Dream header.

ps:
Just to remove some confusion Path();,Sword();, and Weird();
are all the level2 functions.

pps:
Also just wondering why i don't have to call the level2 functions in my main.cpp?

final thought:
Thanks for you time and have a nice day!

ps final thoughts:
This is a portal 1 references.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to call `main()` in a C++ program.  Period.
In C, yes, but in C++, no.  When you do have a call to `main()` in your program, you are invoking undefined behaviour, and the program may do anything.

Comment: How do you suggest i return to main ?

Comment: Not by calling it...use a loop!

Comment: Actually, you should probably create a `std::string GetNextCommand()` function and a  `DoNextCommand(std::string)` function. Put those two in a loop. Probably a `do { } while(stillAlive);` loop :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't compare c strings with ==. Use strcmp() instead. Since this is c++, you should be using std::string anyway. Also, z[5] is not big enough to hold "Dream" or other 5 character strings.